# How do you split a fraction into a sum of fractions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

To add: $$\frac25+\frac37=\frac{14+15}{35}=\frac{29}{35}$$
But if asked to return $\frac{29}{35}$ to a sum of fractions how would one go about this?
My attempt: $$\frac{29}{35}=\frac{29}{(5)(7)}=\frac{a}{5}+\frac{b}{7};where:  7a+5b=29$$
But I can't figure out how to solve for a and b. If I had another equation in terms of a and b I could use simultaneous equations but I can't find one.

I need this method to solve:
$$\frac{5x^{4}+9x^{2}+4x}{x^{5}+3x^{3}+2x^{2}+6}=\frac{3x^{2}}{x^{3}+2}+\frac{2x}{x^{2}+3}$$

Note there may be more than one possible answer. Can we consider two scenarios.
(1) You must return as a sum with specific denominators. The denominators are given.
(2) You can return any sum you like.

Comment: It is easier to solve the polynomial one. Try to let the required coefficient be $a$ and $b$, then compare the coefficients on LHS and RHS.

Comment: Are you familiar with partial fraction decomposition

Comment: Was just about to suggest the same as in the comment above me [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)... But it seems rather too complicated for the question at hand (at least for the explicit numerical part of it). In any case, there can be more than a single solution (in fact, there are probably infinitely many solutions).

Comment: It should be $x^3+2$, not $x^3+3$

Comment: So your question is how to get the partial fractions. Is that correct? If so, the whole of the first part about ordinary fractions is completely irrelevant.

Comment: It seems these kind of questions are solved using Partial-Fraction Decomposition which a few people mentioned and I am new to so I'll have to work on it. But I am content that I now have the method. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that your question is ill-defined. For instance, look at these three fraction-decompositions:
$$
\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6}\\
\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1.27}{4} + \frac{0.73}{4}.
$$
Without further guidance, how should we know which one is wanted? It seems as if the last one's bad, i.e., that you might want integers in the numerator and denominator...but we can do that:
$$
\frac{1}{2} = \frac{127}{400} + \frac{73}{400}.
$$

In your case, the denominator is a product of two primes, $5$ and $7$, and you seem to want integers in the numerator. So let's look at that problem in general:

Suppose $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers, and we're given 
$$
\frac{n}{pq}
$$
where $n$ is some integer (with neither $p$ nor $q$ as a factor), and you'd like to write this as 
$$
\frac{n}{pq} =
\frac{a}{q} + \frac{b}{q}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are integers. Now *that's* a problem I can give some help with!

Multiply through by $pq$ to get
$$
n = ap + bq
$$
i.e., we'd like to express the number $n$ as a combination of the primes $p$ and $q$. Here's how to do that:

Step 1: Express the number $1$ that way, i.e., find numbers $u$ adn $v$ with 
$$
1 = up + vq
$$

{more on this below}

Step 2: Pick $a = nu$ and $b = nv$, and you're done.

But how do you find $u$ and $v$? Answer: something called the "Euclidean algorithm". This allows you to write the GCD of two numbers as a combination of the numbers.

Actually, the things you need come from [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity), which you can read about without my copying it here.

As for applying this to the polynomial question, you can use much the same method...providing the two "factors" are each irreducible polynomials, and that they can be "combined" to form the constant polynomial "1". But for your particular polynomial problem: it may be easiest to do this one by going all the way to partial fractions rather than trying to restrict to the case of integer coefficients, etc. Pretty much any calculus book will have a section on partial fraction decompositions for rational functions.

Comment: Isn't it more likely the OP was asking about partial fractions?

Comment: I (perhaps foolishly) answered the question that OP literally asked, namely "But if asked to return 29/35 to a sum of fractions how would one go about this?" If that's not what OP wanted, so be it. :) OP seems to think that the answer to *this* question will allow a solution to an analogous problem for polynomials (which is partly true), although you and I know that partial fractions is probably a better way to get there.